# What asks for username/password at login? (text login, not graphics)

Tags: login, password

I am working with an Ubuntu Docker image. I've added a couple of users, set passwords and can attach a directory in my host to a directory inside the docker container using the following command:

docker run -i -t \ 
--mount type=bind,source="$(pwd)"/Docker_Run,target=/home/mark/app \
mark/ubuntu /bin/bash

This command starts the mark/ubuntu container and runs /bin/bash which deposits me in Ubuntu as root. I'd like to run something that asks for a username and password like a normal command line login.

Does anyone have an option for this?

Comment: Why? It doesn't add any security; the user running the docker image can modify it at will, and thus change whatever security you add.

Comment: I'm the only user so I'm not worried about security. Mostly a learning process for me but I'd rather enter the environment in my user account than as root.

Answer (score 1):

From `man agetty`:

```
   agetty  opens a tty port, prompts for a login name and invokes the /bin/login command.  It
   is normally invoked by init(8).
```

So, it's either `man agetty` or `man login` that will help you.

Comment: Both choices are interesting and sort of work, but neither works completely correctly.

Comment: /sbin/agetty - gets a login screen identical (I think) to my Ubuntu machine and allows me to log in correctly but I also get the message "TIOCSCTTY failed on /dev/pts/0-bash: cannot set terminal process group (-1): Inappropriate ioctl for device-bash: no job control in this shell". I see some threads on that so I'll study more. Once logged in I cannot do things like 'sudo apt update' as sudo returns "sudo: no tty present and no askpass program specified". So, close but some things to still work out. Thanks!